# z-index layering in IE9, with example, stacking contexts checked (I think)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

I am working on a portfolio project. I have a relatively positioned image in a relatively positioned div. Using z-index I have a fixed position div on top of this, inside of which there are three floated divs, each of which has a cursor url specified in css. All of this is in another div. The aim is to have a previous, play and next cursor displayed on top of an image to control the display of images.

It works well in Safari, Firefox, Chrome. It does not work in IE (9,8 or 7). The cursor does not show when over the image. Somehow, the fixed position div is dropping behind the image, even though it's z-index says it should be above.

I have read a lot on this. I have considered the stacking contexts, and I believe they are OK in my code. I have investigated making all the objects have relative positioning in case fixed and relative positioning is creating different stacking contexts. This did not solve it. I have investigated quirks and standard mode. Nothing seems to work.

I have uploaded stripped back example pages of my problem here:

http://bigflannel.com/portfolio/ie-test

Any help very very gratefully appreciated. I'm 8 hours into debugging and stuck.

The HTML

```
<div id ="website">

    <div id="media-panel">
        <img id="image0" class="image" src="http://bigflannel.com/portfolio/admin/albums/album-5/lg/fk01117.jpg">
    </div><!-- #media-panel -->

    <div id="navigation-panel">
        <div id="left-area"></div>
        <div id="play-pause-area"></div>
        <div id="right-area"></div>
    </div><!-- #navigation-panel -->

</div><!-- #website -->
```

The CSS

```
#website {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
#media-panel {
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.image {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    z-index: 0;
}
#navigation-panel {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 900px;
}
#left-area {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    cursor: url(http://bigflannel.com/development/mobileApp/bigflannel-portfolio/images/prevL.cur), auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 900px;
}
#play-pause-area {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    cursor: url(http://bigflannel.com/development/mobileApp/bigflannel-portfolio/images/playL.cur), auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 900px;
}
#right-area {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    cursor: url(http://bigflannel.com/development/mobileApp/bigflannel-portfolio/images/nextL.cur), auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 900px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately IE is very buggy when it comes to cursors.  This is actually not a z-index issue.  The layering is working as expected.  You can test this by putting a background color on the #navigation-panel as it goes over the image.  It has to do with IE and the behaviour of cursor.

Solution: (for IE9)

```
/* Background with no opacity */
#navigation-panel {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

You can probably fix with earlier versions of IE by using the filter.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had not thought it might be a cursor issue (oddly)! This fixes it. Brilliant.

Comment: Took me a while, but I think I have accepted it, click on the tick.